# After removeFromSuperview completes, a white screen is shown in place

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

So for my application, I add a view (aView) on top of my current view (classesWebView) as a Subview. All the aView is, is a UIView with a UIActivityIndicatorView on top of it that is supposed to animate while the view underneath (classesWebView) loads the appropriate Web Page.

I can see that the classesWebView webpage does appear (aView has an alpha of .5), but as soon as it finishes loading all the way, aView is sent [aView removeFromSuperview] and it disappears but after it goes away, all that's left is a white screen in it's place.

I have done this for two other methods and I don't know why, on only this method, it refuses to cooperate.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. The App is for iOS 6.

viewDidLoad method:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    classesWebView.delegate = self;

    [classesWebView addSubview:aView];

    NSURL *class = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mywebistelink"]; 

    NSURLRequest *classRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:class]; 

    [classesWebView loadRequest:classRequest];   
}
```

webViewDidStartLoad method:

preView and switchView are Activity Indicators.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *) webview
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    if(aView.superview != nil)
    {
        [preView startAnimating];
    }
    else
    {
        [switchView startAnimating];
    }
}
```

webViewDidFinishLoad method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *) webview
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    if(aView.superview != nil)
    {
        [aView removeFromSuperview];
        [preView stopAnimating];
        [preView setOpaque:false];
    }
    else
    {
        [switchView stopAnimating];
        [switchView setOpaque:false];
    }
}
```

[Further clarity: The reason I have the if-statement, is because I want another indicator for the classesWebView when loading pages but I do NOT want it to appear unless aView is gone (since aView already has it's on indicator: preView)]

EDIT: Just to prove that it is ONLY THE removeFromSuperview that is causing the problem, if I call [aView setAlpha:0.0] it disappears and the webPage below it loads properly. But the second that I call [aView removeFromSuperview] the web page turns into a white screen. T_T

Comment: white screen appears means web-page is not loaded properly.

Comment: yes @iManan. I think thats the issue.

Comment: I'm positive it's not that issue. I know the web page loads properly. Without the aView being added as a subview and then being shown, the web page loads fine and is manipulatable. 

It only goes haywire as soon as the [aView removeFromSuperview] is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I never got it to work but I cheated it by just setting [aView setAlpha:0]. That worked for what I needed. Thanks for the suggestions though, guys.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    NSURL *class=[NSURL URLWithString:[yourwebistelink stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:class];

   [self.classesWebView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Didn't fix it. 

The white screen only appears after I call the [aView removeFromSuperview].

I know the webpage loads underneath correctly because 1) I can see it load before it turns white and 2) because when I don't have aView at all, it loads completely fine and works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

try this one.. and try to dont add aView for activityIndicator., try this this one for indicating activityIndicator

```
UIWebView * classesWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];

[classesWebView addSubview:activityIndicator];
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating]; //for activityIndicator

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:weburl];
classesWebView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 768, 400);
[classesWebView setScalesPageToFit:NO];
[classesWebView loadRequest:request];


- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)thisWebView
{

}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)thisWebView
{
[self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

    [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
}
```

if still webView is displaying blank white, then you have to encode your url by this one

```
NSString *encodedString=[graphStringUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *weburl = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:weburl];
```

then load this **request** in webView

```
[classesWebView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: So. I KNOW that my webpage is loading correctly because if I remove the [aView removeFromSuperview] it loads underneath it and it allows me to scroll it and click links.

It only becomes a problem as soon as I add that one line. 

This aView was added as a afterthought as a nice way to see a full screen load indicator. I verified it was working beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be adding subviews to a `UIWebView`.  Try adding `aView` to the view that contains your `classesWebView` and see if that fixes the problem.